# Spring Security 5 unable to add custom AccessDecisionManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem in my Spring application to use a custom AccessDecisionManager.
It is really a little customization as I just want the RoleVoter to have no rolePrefix :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter   {

...

 @Bean
    public AuthenticatedVoter authenticatedVoter(){
        return new AuthenticatedVoter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RoleVoter roleVoter(){
        RoleVoter roleVoter = new RoleVoter();
        roleVoter.setRolePrefix("");

        return roleVoter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
        decisionVoters.add(roleVoter());
        decisionVoters.add(authenticatedVoter());

        return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }

...

}
```

It seems simple, but when I declare the accessDecisionManager in the configure method like that :

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/studies").hasAnyRole("SITE_ADMIN", "ADMIN")

                ...

                .antMatchers("/terms.app").permitAll()

                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())
                .and().httpBasic()

                .authenticationEntryPoint(keycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()

                .addFilterBefore(characterEncodingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), ConcurrentSessionFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
                .addFilterAt(logoutFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)

                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true).and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
    }
```

I got the following exception at startup :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [permitAll, permitAll, hasAnyRole('ROLE_SITE_ADMIN','ROLE_ADMIN'), ... , authenticated]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [permitAll, permitAll, hasAnyRole('ROLE_SITE_ADMIN','ROLE_ADMIN'), ... , authenticated]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [permitAll, permitAll, hasAnyRole('ROLE_SITE_ADMIN','ROLE_ADMIN'), ... , authenticated]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.createFilterSecurityInterceptor(AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.configure(AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.configure(ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.configure(AbstractInterceptUrlConfigurer.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:383)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:329)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:333)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

I tried a lot of things, I debugged the Spring code, but I was not able to find a valid solution...
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: No it didn't, it doesn't work with the suggested modifications.

Comment: Did you try adding a `WebExpressionVoter`? That is what is what resolves `permitAll`, `authenticated` etc

Comment: Yes, in fact I answerd a little bit too fast, it solved my problem of starting the application, but the ROLE prefix must still be present and I want no prefix. I guess I will create another question for that. Thank you for your help !